# illustrator: create new layers from intersection of other layers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have two path shapes.  They overlap in some places and do not overlap in other places.

I want to create new layers for every place where the existing shapes overlap and new layers for every where they do not.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. Do you want each black shape on it's own "layer"? Note, your layer panel shows the objects, and only 1 layer.

Comment: @Scott yes, I want the each black shape on its own layer. Sorry about confusing layer and objects.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that comes to mind is to elaborate the paths, group them accordingly and then put them in separate layers as you want! Select both the paths and then use this button:

[image]

Comment: I agree with the Pathfinder suggestion to generate the shapes, and instead of moving each to its own layer you could use the sub-layers that are shown in each expanded layer, as in your original screen shot.